# Create role which can run any queries on all databases postgresql

Tags: postgresql

theres a default postgres user (superuser) hes able to run some random queries on all databases like select * from regions; etc.
i do have a 7 databases in pgadmin tool 1 user which is postgres and i created role service_user and granted all privileges to service_user(GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO service_user;), but when i sign in to different database as service_user im not able to run queries, it says permission denied. so i need to login to that db as superuser grant all privileges again and then service_user is able to tun queries.
So my question is how can i grant all privileges to this service_user so he can login to any database and run queries. i can do it manually but its 7 databases i need to login and log out 7 times to every database. what if i have 500 databases running. keep in mind service_user shoould not be superuser. just read-write permissions and able to run any queries in any 7 databases. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAXOx.png)

Comment: If you make this user the owner of all the databases and let that user create the tables etc then they will automatically have access to their contents. They will also be able to drop tables etc. though. Is that what you are after?

Comment: you can grant the [pg_read_all_data](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/predefined-roles.html) role

Comment: Yes @RichardHuxton

Comment: @RichardHuxton it is owner already but i did it manually on every single database. my question is how i can make it with single command to be owner for 100 databases? Appreciate any help

Comment: you could do it in a DO block with plpgsql and EXECUTE or via some shell/perl/python scripting easily enough - use the pg_database system view to get a list of databases.

Comment: i got like 500 databases running. i tried to run grant pg_read_all_data to service_user; while logged in postgres database. then tried to log in to different database with service user select * from region; still permission denied. seems like this command worked only within postgres database its like echosystem.

Comment: so what is the right command like alter <db_name> owner to service_user;  but this is single database i got 500 of them. may be not to change the owner i just need service user to be able to read and modify content in all databases even create roles and stuff. not a superuser.

Comment: GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO service_user;   THIS command works perfect it doesnt change the owner of database but gives the ability to read the content on all tables. but the problem as i said this command is for a single database i need for 500 databases. any help would be great!!!

Comment: @RichardHuxton what do u think. may be grant select on database?

Comment: also all these commands should be run with postgres superuser right?